# When changing recipe size, do I proportionally change bake time?

Tags: baking, cooking-time

I'm making chocolate cupcakes and halving the recipe. Do I halve the baking time as well? I'm not changing pans, it's a normal cupcake tin.

Comment: Is each cupcake the same size as in the original recipe, and you are just making half as many? Or are you making half-sized cupcakes?

Answer (score 4):

Baking times are based on the size of what's in the oven. If making 1, 3, 6, 12, 24 or 48 cupcakes of the same size, you bake them the same time, as each one "sees" the oven the same way or has the same volume/thickness from the outside where the heat is to the center.

If making mini-cupcakes or giant cupcakes, or baking a cake using a cupcake recipe, the baking time needs to change with the size of what goes into the oven full of batter, as there is more or less batter to be cooked through from the outside edge and bottom/top of the pan.

Comment: It might help to add that the changes in baking time do not scale linearly with the size of the item to be baked. In other words, baking a cake that is twice the size in one pan as the recipe specifies does not mean you should bake it twice as long. I'd estimate 10% - 30% longer in a case like that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yeah, the square cube law makes such scaling tricky.